# How to share weights among subset of input features with keras

Tags: python, keras, neural-network

In this neural network, there are 9 input features:

```
  f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,f6,f7,f8,f9
```

I want some of the input features, but not all, to have identical weights between the input layer and the first hidden layer.  All remaining layers will not have any shared weights.

```
  f1,f2,f3 should share the same weights
  f4,f5,f6 should share the same weights
  f7 should not share weights with other features
  f8 should not share weights with other features
  f9 should not share weights with other features
```

I'm pretty sure I need 1D convolutions, but not on the entire layer.  I may have missed it, but haven't seen this use case documented. Any ideas how to do this in Keras?

Rephrasing the question, what is the right way to express equal importance among a group of features?

Features (`f1`, `f2`, `f3`) have equal importance when predicting the output class.  Features (`f4`, `f5`, `f6`) also have equal importance when predicting the output class.

There are three possible predicted classes.  Features `f1` and `f4` are evidence for output classA. Features `f2` and `f5` are evidence for output `classB`. Features `f3` and `f6` are evidence for output `classC`.

Is there a way to reduce the number of parameters in the network by sharing parameters among the equal-importance features?

Answer (score 0):

Equivalent to summing `f1+f2+f3` and `f4+f5+f6` before a dense layer.

Suggestion of layer to sum:

```
from keras.layers import Lambda
import keras.backend as K

def sumFeatures(x):
    f1_3 = x[:,:3]
    f4_6 = x[:,3:6]

    return K.concatenate(
        [
            K.sum(f1_3, axis=-1, keepdims=True),
            K.sum(f4_6, axis=-1, keepdims=True),
            x[:,6:]
        ], axis=-1)
```

Sequential model:

```
model.add(Lambda(sumFeatures))
```

Functional Model:

```
outputTensor = Lambda(sumFeatures)(inputTensor)
```

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply.  Maybe I need to rephrase my question.  Features (1,2,3) are independent evidence for different output classes and should not be combined into a single feature.  Likewise for features (4,5,6).  But they have equal importance.  What is the right way to express equal importance?

Comment: Equal importance regarding what, the loss function? If you're using standard loss functions, all features have equal importance.

Comment: Features (f1,f2,f3) have equal importance regarding the predicted output class.  Features (f4,f5,f6) have equal importance regarding the predicted output class.  There are 3 possible output classes.  Features f1 and f4 are evidence for output classA.  Features f2 and f5 are evidence for output classB.  Features f3 and f6 are evidence for output classC.